# Moving from Netbeans to Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, visual-studio-2022

I have been using Netbeans IDE 8.2 to work on a C++ code project hosted on a Ubuntu server but want to move to using Visual Studio 2022

For Netbeans I used ...

- View -> Toolbars -> Remote
- Manage Hosts -> Add
  .. to connect to the remote Ubuntu server ..
  Then ..
- Create OR Open Remote C/C++ Project
- C/C++ project with existing sources
- Then pointed to the folder path to my SRC files
  This allowed me to work on the existing project that is already on the Ubuntu server with Netbeans

With Visual Studio 2022 I -think- the remote connection part is handled with ..

- Tools -> Options -> Cross Platform -> Connection Manager -> Add
  I have filled in the details for this and Verified the connection and can even open an SSH terminal with ..
- View -> Terminal
  Which lets me see the files on the Ubuntu server in a terminal

Not sure what steps to take to "Open remote project with existing sources" in Visual Studio 2022 like I do in Netbeans to view/edit the files in Solution Explorer